# Tailwind css classes does not work until I change and save some lines in styles.scss or tailwind.config.js files

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I'm using the latest angular and tailwind CSS version! It works fine!

But I changed some tailwind CSS classes and saved the HTML file, Tailwind CSS classes did not load right away!

```
<div class="bg-blue-400"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="bg-blue-800"></div>
```

I had to change something in styles.scss file or tailwind.config.js file and then save it to reflect the new classes!

Comment: What does *I changed some tailwind CSS class* mean? We need a [mcve] here

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem with Angular 13 and TailwindCSS v3, and have found a solution [in the Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss):

Did you create the postcss.config.js file at the root of your project (same level as tailwind.config.js)?

**postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

You also need to check in the tailwind.config.js file that the `content` correctly points to your components.

Comment: This solution works. 

The problem is within the Tailwind documentation, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular - it does not say to create a file postcss.config.js !

Comment: It still doesn't work! I have to stop the server and then start to load new changes! It doesn't reflect changes in the browser either!

Comment: I had the same issue before I added this file at the same level as tailwind.config.js. 
Can you include screenshots of your project + tailwind config file in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with **Angular**, where updating the tailwind classes on an html element didn't get reflected in watch mode, except if I reloaded the server or modified a css/scss file or config file.
To solve it, you should enable **ESBuild** on the project (but be aware that it is still in development https://angular.io/guide/esbuild), by modifying the **architect.build.builder** attribute inside **angular.json**, like so:

```
...
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
...
```

Comment: Exact same problem with Angular 17 with SCSS and Tailwind. Saving a HTML file removes styles, but saving a SCSS file re-applies them. Seems Tailwind and SCSS don't play well together with Angular.